# Launchd - Run as if you're logged in as a user using sudo

Tags: macos, mac, imac, launchd

Is there a way to do this?

Basically I'm trying to run a script that needs to launch a program.

Putting the script in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` works fine, but everything gets run as if its the root user. This doesn't work because it needs to run as if its a real user, but using the `sudo` command.

So I moved the script to `~/Library/LaunchDaemons` but now it won't launch the program, presumably because its getting run as the user and not with `sudo` permissions.

So I'm stuck. Logging in as the user and going to a terminal and running:

```
sudo my_command_which_launches_a_program
```

Works absolutely fine, and exactly how its meant to work. So I want to basically emulate that, but in a Launchd script, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you put the script in the directories mentioned or the launchd plist?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm talking about a plist which runs the script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You put the plist into /Library/LaunchDaemons but edit it to say which user the script will run as

The key you need to add is UserName. For example I run a newserver as user _news

```xml
<key>UserName</key>
<string>_news</string>
```

Documented in [Apple's launchd man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/5/launchd.plist/)

Comment: Unlike LaunchAgents, LaunchDeamon cannot use `UserName`. They run without loggin in a user.

Comment: @Julian where is this documented - and I think this used to work so what OS X chnage this

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert - just run it as root. `sudo launchctl .....` for your UserName to be used by launchtl. This is docummented in the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) `UserName <string>
     This optional key specifies the user to run the job as. This key is only applicable when launchd is
     running as root.`

Comment: On macOS `launchd` is always run as root. The man page only covers this for non-macOS systems.

Answer (score 3):

> it needs to run as if its a real user, but using the sudo command

I think this belies a false assumption you are making. When a user runs `sudo foobar`, then the `foobar` command is run by the `root` user.

The only things that can be different when running `foobar` as root (instead of the user running `sudo foobar`) are the shell and environment variables available such as `$HOME` or `$PATH`.

If your application requires a specific shell or environment variable, *just ensure that that shell or environment variable is set by the LaunchDaemon you are creating*. That will save you a lot of heartache over trying to get `launchd` to replicate the exact experience of a specific user running `sudo foobar`.

**To those downvoting**, this information is backed up multiple times on StackExchange [here](https://superuser.com/a/771523/57300), [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/592838/19047), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su#comment80057_70536) for starters.